# C# MVC Model DisplayName conditional

Tags: asp.net-mvc, localization

I am working on a MVC project. I have model called person whose attributes are Name and Country. 
in my model i have used  `[DisplayName("Name")]
                          public string Name{ get; set; }`

I want that if Country is England DisplayNAme should be Name  , if country is Netherlands then Display name should be Naam.

In short can we make DisplayName conditional in model itsefl? or can we assign more than one displayname to attribute??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, add a resource file for each language with a key of Name. You can then decorate your class Properties with something like this:

```
[Display(Name = "Name", ResourceType = typeof(MyResources))]
```

Further details on `Display` [can be found here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayattribute.aspx), and [localization and MVC in general here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/181738/Creating-a-Bilingual-ASP-NET-MVC3-Application-Part).

Comment: Ok, I've done that. I think you get more reputation for accepting an answer too...